# xml parsing of img src from the XML response

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, asihttprequest

I have an xml response as:

```
{
    text = "<img alt=\"Marco Bueno\" src=\"http://u.goal.com/136600/136687_thumb.jpg\" style=\"float: left;margin:0 10px 10px 10px;\" title=\"Marco Bueno\" /><p style=\"float:left;\">Herrera is currently on national team duty representing the U-23 side that has already made history at the Toulon Tournament, while Bueno won the U-17 World Cup in 2011</p>";
}
```

now i want to get img src(URL) from this. How can i get that?

I am using asihttpRequest library for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no objective-c xml parser in the iOS SDK, but you do have the libxml2 C library. You could use one of several open source objective-c xml parser implementations that are out there, for instance: https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML

Once you have included KissXML in your project, you could just do something like this (Assuming your response is in JSON and the XML is only one of the values of your JSON response):

```
 NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

 NSString xmlString = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"text"];

 NSXMLDocument *xml = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:nil];

 NSString *url = [[[[xml rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"body/img/@src" error:nil] lastObject] stringValue];

 NSLog(@"%@", url);
```